# Unable to boot, motherboard beeps every 5 seconds or so

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, display

A couple of weeks ago, my computer suddently crashed (the screen blinked twice, and then the computer shut down).

Upon restarting it, I got no picture and my motherboard made one long and three short beeps.

After trying all sorts of things, I decided to send in my GPU, and I had a replacement sent, but after installing it yesterday, it seemed to work, but it was just hanging at the motherboard splashscreen. I then tried to enter BIOS to see if there was something wrong with the boot settings, but I couldn't enter BIOS. After hitting DEL a few times, the onboard speaker would start making a weird clicking sound every time I hit a key on my keyboard.

After having tried restarting a few times, It went back to doing the same thing as before I installed the new GPU... One long, three short beeps.

**EDIT**

**Motherboard:** Gigabyte X79-UD7
**CPU:** Intel i7-3930k 3.4Ghz
**GPU:** ASUS Geforce GTX 670
**RAM:** 16GB Corsair Vengance
**Powersupply:** Coolermaster Silent Pro Gold 1000W
**Harddrive:** 1x 1TB Western Digital, 1x 120Gb Corsair

**EDIT 2**

Right, so now I get a picture, but it hangs at debug code 62... I've done a bit of research and this seems to be a problem with the new sandy bridge architecture... Time to RMA my motherboard..... Thanks for all the suggestions, though! :)

Comment: Do you have more then 1 PCI-E 16x slots available for your graphics card? Could be a dodgy PCI-E slot.

Comment: what motherboard?

Comment: It's a Gigabyte X79-UD7 :)

Comment: According to the [manual of your motherboard](http://ca.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4047#manual), your board should have a debug LED. What is it saying?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, when I had just installed the new GPU, it was booting as uaual, untill the screen where I can choose to enter BIOS (which didn't work) The Debug Display shows code 64, which seems to be a memory issue, but that doesn't explain why my old GPU was broken.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your RAM as well? just in case. if you have more than 1 stick, check the RAM by running one stick at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Based upon your new update to the OP

Possibility 1)

The beep code indicates an issue with the VGA or even Enhanced Graphics Adapter (EGA); and you've said you've changed your GPU. Basically your machine thinks the GPU RAM is bad, or can't detect it correctly (maybe it's not seated properly).

I would test another graphics processor as well (is there one built in on your motherboard?) (if you have a spare/old one).

At this stage though my gut feeling thinks it could be a faulty motherboard.

Possibility 2)

The beep code indicates a conventional memory failure

You need to test just 1 RAM chip at a time, but it may also be the memory location (the slot), all RAM may be corrupted or it's possible it's not seated correctly.

[Beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)

Comment: Really...? The OP says **1 long 3 short**. Also I don't think every motherboards act the same.

Comment: @AlvinWong Yes, I know it says 1 long and 3 short, and this can indicate either RAM or Video/Video RAM issue. See my updated Beep codes for different BIOS in link in my post.